# Porting time APIs from Linux to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, time, porting, timeval

I have an application that I am porting to Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 that builds and runs fine on Linux.

I am having trouble with the time routines, my Linux code looks like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef long long Usec;

inline Usec timevalToUsec(const timeval &tv)
{
  return (((Usec) tv.tv_sec) * 1000000) + ((Usec) tv.tv_usec);
}
```

But the compiler fails on the `sys/time.h` header file:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
      'sys/time.h': No such file or directory
```

If I change the include to just `time.h` I get a different error with timeval not being defined:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
      Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

This is due to the `timeval` not being defined.

Is including `time.h` instead of `sys/time.h` correct, and if so, where do I get the definition of `struct timeval` in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `winsock2.h` header fill will pull in [`struct timeval`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since it's used in calls like `select`.

Answer (score 3):

It exists, just not in "sys/time.h".  Timeval is in, interestingly, Winsock2.h.